# django form validation: validating initial values

Tags: django, validation, forms

I have a django form (forms.Form). Each and every form fields have initial values like,

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
  city = forms.CharField(initial="Your city here")
```

When some one posts this form without changing the initial value (ie. Without entering anything as city, the city field will be "Your city here") . form.is_valid() does not raise a validation error. Is there any way i can make the validation fail? Is there any inbuilt method/property available that i can call/set to make form validation to fail? Or do i have to manually validate it?

Comment: Why should it fail if it's a plain CharField?

Comment: Agree with your point. But it is not an expected behavior for the application i am developing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have to manually do the validation using the Django forms [clean_fieldname](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) method as follows:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    city = forms.CharField(initial='Your city here')

    def clean_city(self):
        city_name = self.cleaned_data['city']
        if city_name in ['Your city here']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Enter a city name.')
        return city_name
```

If you are using Django 1.2 or upwards, [custom validators](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#validators) would be worth the effort.